# jQuery : Binding a append function to a newly appended div

Tags: jquery

In a webpage,there are number of posts contained in divs with the class name '`postContainer`'.The code below would add a button to each `div`.

```
$('.postContainer').find('.fileText')
      .append('<button class="exbutton d1" type="button">postname</button>');
```

My code works initially,but as a new post appears by `ajax`, it's div doesn't have the button

Comment: Can you use jsfiddle or the snippet tool to explain the problem better?

Comment: `.find()` just finds the elements that currently exist. There's no way to make this happen automatically in the future, unless you run it in an event handler.

Comment: Can you clarify the issue further?

Comment: can you share some more relevant code? Like when do you call this piece of code? If you are expecting a `button` be added automatically when a `.postContainer` element is added to the DOM in the future, then you need to add an event handler.

Comment: Maybe look at [Mutation Observers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) which allow you to execute code when the DOM is modified.

Comment: After appending new `postContainer`, inside same event/function, you need to append another button.

Comment: clicking the add button appends a new div with class postContainer. But the new div doesn't contain 'postname' button unlike the original http://jsfiddle.net/xtb51wed/

Comment: updated link : https://jsfiddle.net/ff2v0q6v/

Comment: Why would the newly appended div contain a button? You're appending a div. That's all. Where would a button come from? You're not cloning your existing div. Your question is unclear.

Comment: Sorry. I should've been more clear. In a webpage,there are number of posts contained in divs with the class name 'postContainer'. I'm wrinting an script that would add a button to each div. My code works initially,but as a new post appears by ajax, it's div doesn't have the button.

Comment: @SaiKrishna well, than expand on your existing problem with more code and words, because no-one can tell what's all about from your question-alone.

Comment: Thank you. I have updated my question

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
$("body").find('.postContainer').each(function(){
  var $this = $(this);
  if($this.find('.exbutton').length === 0) {
      $this.append('<button class="exbutton d1" type="button">postname</button>');
  }
  });
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score -1):

Try to do it this way: https://jsfiddle.net/ff2v0q6v/1/

```js
var AJAXcontent = "Lorem <b>ipsum</b> dolor sit amet..."; // The AJAX post HTML

// OK. now...

var $exbutton = $("<button/>", {
  "class": "exbutton d1",
  type: "button",
  text: "postname"
});


$("<div/>", {
  "class": "postContainer",
  html: AJAXcontent,   // 1. Insert the post content
  append: $exbutton,   // 2. append the button
  appendTo: "body"     // 3. append the DIV wherever you want
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```